# Resize columns height on hide/show divs

Tags: jquery

I've a html page with two columns.

```
<div class="span2 sameht">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="hidelevel">something</div>
        <div class="hidelevel">something</div>
        <div>something</div>
        <div>something</div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="span3 sameht">
    <div class="content">
        <div>something</div>
        <div>something</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

to have the same height for the columns I used this code

```
$( function() {
    var maxHeight = 0
    $('.sameht').each(function() {
        if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
            maxHeight = $(this).height();
        }
});
$('.sameht').height(maxHeight);
});
```

Now, when I hide the div (`.hidelevel` class) in this way the columns height is not dynamically resized.

```
$(function() {
    $(".hidelevel").hide();
})
```

Is it possible to re-size the height of the columns every time I hide/show `<div>`s?

Thanks

Comment: can you please build a working fiddle with your code?

Comment: put your two divs in a parent div. when you will hide/show the tallest one, the parent div will automaticly adjust, not jquery trick

Comment: You have a div called span. This can't end well.

Comment: can you call the same function that you are using at the time of page load. $('.sameht').each()... when you hide the hidelevel divs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for hide function:

```
    $(function () {

        $(".hidelevel").hide();
//after hide div. 1) set height to auto and 2) resize both div 
        var maxHeight = 0
//1) set height to auto 
        $('.sameht').css({ 'height': 'auto' });
//2) resize both div 
        $('.sameht').each(function () {
            if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = $(this).height();
            }
        });
        $('.sameht').height(maxHeight);

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#hidelevel").hide(); will not work. Because these is no element having hidelevel id.
```

use this one:

```
$(".hidelevel").hide();
```

Comment: Sorry, this is a my writing mistake. In my code is $(".hidelevel")

Answer (score 0):

Capture the code that toggles the height in a function.  Then call this function when you hide the elements.

**Javascript**

```
$( function() {
   adjustHeight();
    $("#toggle").click(function(){
        $(".hidelevel").toggle();
        adjustHeight();
    });
});


function adjustHeight(){
var maxHeight = 0
$('.sameht').each(function() {
    if ($(this).height() > maxHeight) {
    maxHeight = $(this).height();
    }
});
$('.sameht').height(maxHeight);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="span2 sameht">

    <div class="content">

        <div class="hidelevel">something</div>
        <div class="hidelevel">something</div>
        <div>something</div>
        <div>something</div>

    </div>

</div>

<div class="span3 sameht">

    <div class="content">

        <div>something</div>
        <div>something</div>

    </div>

</div>

<div id="toggle">Toogle Visibility</div>
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/jXgLd/

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn your height-adjuster into a function, so that you can run it at any time:

```
function fixHeight() {
    var maxHeight = Math.max.apply(this, $('.sameht').map(function() { return $(this).height(); }));
    $('.sameht').height(maxHeight);
});
```

`.hide` accepts a callback. Just make sure you call that whenever you've hidden an element (or, just make sure you call it whenever the heights change for any reason):

```
$(function() {
    $('#hidelevel').hide(fixHeight);
});
```

Comment: I tried this way but not working. Now the columns aren't the same :(